# UITextField textColor changed after clearing the text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextfield, textcolor

The text color starts out as red and changes to blue after clearing the text.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30)];
    self.textField.textColor = UIColor.blueColor;
    self.textField.text = @"hello world";
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = self.textField.attributedText;
    NSMutableAttributedString *mAttributedText = attributedText.mutableCopy;
    [attributedText enumerateAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length) options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        [mAttributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:UIColor.redColor range:range];
    }];
    self.textField.attributedText = mAttributedText;
    
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];
}

@end
```

The expectation is that the text should always remain red. Why does UITextField textColor changed after clearing the text?

Comment: why you need to have two colors when you always want red ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri It's just a demo. I will change textColor using setAttributedText: at  specific time. After clearing the text, I wish textColor remains the same.

Comment: once you clear the text, you no longer have the attributed text attributes applied, you need to re apply them while you were typing the text.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Fine, but it's confusing. After invoke setAttributedText:, property textColor also changes to red color, Why did it turn back to blue in the end?

Comment: the attributes you apply initially will get cleared as you removed the text by backspacing, at this point it will fallback to blue color, as that is what you set the text color of your text field.